# seaborn kdeplot x axis scaling?

Tags: seaborn

I have a histogram of my data: 
h is a 1-d array of counts
x is a 1-d array of bin values

Now if I do:
sns.kdeplot(h, shade=True);

I get a plot where x-axis goes from -20 to 100, which has nothing to do with
my original x data.  How do I get the x-axis scaled to match my data?

Comment: What version are you using? This sounds like a bug in 0.3.0 that was fixed in 0.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I see I misunderstood the input to kde.  It wants the original values.  I had already created a histogram and wanted to feed that to kde.

In my histogram I have h.buckets, and h.results.  I did

```
def hist_to_values (hist):
    ret = []
    for x,y in zip (hist.buckets, h.results):
        ret.extend ([x] * y)
    return np.array (ret)
```

Then feed this to kde, and I got the results I expect.